# Required version of proj4.js with OpenLayers 4.6.4

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I am currently using the version 2.2.2 of proj4.js with OpenLayers 4.6.4 and I plan to move to the version 2.4.3 of proj4.js because it resolves a defect that I have. However, I wanted to know if OpenLayers 4.6.4 works with proj4.js 2.4.3.